# How to Create a Table in Violin Plot?

Tags: r

Newbie to R!

I have created a violin plot with a box plot in it. Using the following code.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(vp4melted, aes(x = Diabetes,y = Range, fill = Diabetes)) +
  geom_violin(trim = FALSE) +
  theme_classic() +              #Theme classic removes the grey background
  stat_summary(fun = mean,     #Just change median to mean for the mean point
               geom = "point",
               size = 2,
               color = "red") +
  geom_boxplot(width=0.1)
```

[image]

I want to create a table in the Violin Plot for 25% Percentile, Median, 75% Percentile. Just like the image above.

Is it Possible in R?

Here is the sample dataset -

```
 vp4melted <- structure(list(Diabetes = c("Without Diabetes", "Without Diabetes", "Without Diabetes", "Without Diabetes", "Without Diabetes", "Without Diabetes", "Without Diabetes", "Without Diabetes", "Without Diabetes", "Without Diabetes","With Diabetes","With Diabetes","With Diabetes","With Diabetes","With Diabetes","With Diabetes","With Diabetes","With Diabetes","With Diabetes", "With Diabetes),
               Range = c("151", "150","145","152","153","147","148","145","142","146","150","148","151","148","150","150","150","149", "145","150")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One potential approach:

```r
library(tidyverse)

vp4melted <- structure(list(Diabetes = c("Without Diabetes", "Without Diabetes", "Without Diabetes", "Without Diabetes", "Without Diabetes", "Without Diabetes", "Without Diabetes", "Without Diabetes", "Without Diabetes", "Without Diabetes","With Diabetes","With Diabetes","With Diabetes","With Diabetes","With Diabetes","With Diabetes","With Diabetes","With Diabetes","With Diabetes", "With Diabetes"),
               Range = c("151", "150","145","152","153","147","148","145","142","146","150","148","151","148","150","150","150","149", "145","150")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))

p1 <- ggplot(vp4melted, aes(x = Diabetes,y = as.numeric(Range), fill = Diabetes)) +
  geom_violin(trim = FALSE) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 20) +              #Theme classic removes the grey background
  stat_summary(fun = mean,     #Just change median to mean for the mean point
               geom = "point",
               size = 2,
               color = "red") +
  geom_boxplot(width=0.1) +
  ylab("Range") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")

p2 <- vp4melted %>%
  group_by(Diabetes) %>%
  mutate(`25% Percentile` = summary(as.numeric(Range))[[2]],
         Median = summary(as.numeric(Range))[[3]],
         `75% Percentile` = summary(as.numeric(Range))[[4]]) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Diabetes, Range)) %>%
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels = c("75% Percentile", "Median", "25% Percentile"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Diabetes, y = name, label = value)) +
  geom_text(size = 4, check_overlap = TRUE) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(1.5, 2.5),
             linewidth = 0.1) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1.5,
             linewidth = 0.1)

library(patchwork)
p1 / p2 + patchwork::plot_layout(heights = c(0.8, 0.2))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hey! It worked. Thank you. Is it possible to create 10 units interval on Y-axis? My dataset is huge and my Y-axis looks like 80, 100, 120.

Comment: Yep; in the first plot ("p1") add `+ scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 120, 10))` to get tick marks at 0, 20, 40, 60 ... 120. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much it worked!

Comment: You're welcome; thanks for including all of the required details in your question @Ray - glad you solved your problem